# Selecting PageSize DataTable in Angular 2

Tags: angular

[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRIgr.png)

**This is my method SetPageSize in component.ts**

```
setPageSize(pages: number) {

let abc = this.showdefaultpage;
abc = 10;

this.inspectorService.getAllData(pages, abc)
  .subscribe(
  data => {
    this.allpagingData = [];
    for (let index in data.inspectors) {
      this.allpagingData.push({
        "id": data.inspectors[index].id,
        "employeeNumber": data.inspectors[index].employeeNumber,
        "name": data.inspectors[index].name,
        "isActive": data.inspectors[index].isActive
      });
    }

    this.totalData = data.totalInspectorViewed;
    this.setPage(pages);
  },
  error => console.log(error));
}
```

**This is my html to setPageSize the datatable**

```
<div style="padding-left: 11px;" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Row: </span>
  <select style="width: 7%" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pageSize" name="pageSize" (change)="setPageSize(pages)">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

but in my method only changed to 10 rowsdata,please help me... how to make the method pageSize can select the rowsdata to 5,10 and 15. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

**this is the answer my method**

```
setPageSize(pages: number) {

let abc = this.showdefaultpage;

if (abc == 5) {
  this.inspectorService.getAllData(pages, abc)
    .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.allpagingData = [];
      for (let index in data.inspectors) {
        this.allpagingData.push({
          "id": data.inspectors[index].id,
          "employeeNumber": data.inspectors[index].employeeNumber,
          "name": data.inspectors[index].name,
          "isActive": data.inspectors[index].isActive
        });
      }

      this.totalData = data.totalInspectorViewed;
      this.setPage(pages);
    },
    error => console.log(error));
}
else if (abc == 10) {
  this.inspectorService.getAllData(pages, abc)
    .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.allpagingData = [];
      for (let index in data.inspectors) {
        this.allpagingData.push({
          "id": data.inspectors[index].id,
          "employeeNumber": data.inspectors[index].employeeNumber,
          "name": data.inspectors[index].name,
          "isActive": data.inspectors[index].isActive
        });
      }

      this.totalData = data.totalInspectorViewed;
      this.setPage(pages);
    },
    error => console.log(error));
}

else if (abc == 15) {
  this.inspectorService.getAllData(pages, abc)
    .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.allpagingData = [];
      for (let index in data.inspectors) {
        this.allpagingData.push({
          "id": data.inspectors[index].id,
          "employeeNumber": data.inspectors[index].employeeNumber,
          "name": data.inspectors[index].name,
          "isActive": data.inspectors[index].isActive
        });
      }

      this.totalData = data.totalInspectorViewed;
      this.setPage(pages);
    },
    error => console.log(error));
}

}
```